# How do I use a algorithm to sort through java objects in a Java GUI program

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, oop, user-interface

how can I put these guitars tab entries into a algorithm (from lowest to
highest rank).Based on the rank that I set them to in that part of the forms textField? The
program takes guitar notes in JTextFields then saves them to a GuitarTab[] array. And, has
Buttons and everything else to navigate through the list though not shown here
(previousBtn, nextBtn, searchBtn, etc). However, how do I navigate through the list with
each "GuitarTab Object" sorted from lowest to highest rank, and then have them in that
order when I press the nextBtn and previosBtn?
It has a JChecked Box to enable the algorithm to happen then a search button to make them
appear. But when I click the search button nothing appears?

```
      public class Guitars  {


       
       public String tabName;
       public String eString;
       public String bString;
       public String gString;
       public String dString;
       public String aString;
       public String lowEString;
       public int rank;
       
       
       public int getRank( ) {
           return rank;
       }
       
       public void setRank(int r) {
           rank = r;
       };
```

---

```
public void saveBtnActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       int j;
       int parsedString;
       String rtrvdString;
       numberEntries++ ;
       currentTabEntry = 1;
       int i;
       if (numberEntries != 1) {
          do {
     if (tabNameFld.getText( ).compareTo(myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].tabName) < 0)
                  break;
              currentTabEntry++;
          }
                while (currentTabEntry < numberEntries);
       }
        if (currentTabEntry != numberEntries) {
            for (i = 0; i >= currentTabEntry + 1; i--) {
                myTablatures[i - 1] = myTablatures[i - 2];
                myTablatures[i - 2] = new GuitarTab( );
            }
        }
        
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1] = new GuitarTab( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].tabName = tabNameFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].eString = eTxtFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].bString = bTxtFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].gString = gTxtFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].dString = dTxtFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].aString = aTxtFld.getText( );
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].lowEString = lowETxtFld.getText( );
       
         try {
             rtrvdString = rankFld.getText( );
             parsedString = Integer.valueOf(rtrvdString); 
         gtrTab.setRank(parsedString);
         myTablatures[currentTabEntry - 1].rank = parsedString;
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace( );
         }
         //Present Currenty Entry
         shwEntry(currentTabEntry);
   }

 //Sort Entries Based On Rank From Smallest Rank to Greater
      public void sortRnkLwToHi(GuitarTab[ ] myTablatures) {
          int a;
          int b;
          int i;
          myTablatures = TabEntryWn.myTablatures;
          GuitarTab tab;
          
          int hiSubscript = myTablatures.length - 1;
          for (a = 0; a < hiSubscript; a++) {
              for (b = 0; b < hiSubscript; b++);
              if (myTablatures[ b ].rank > myTablatures[b + 1].rank) {
                  tab = myTablatures[ b ];
                  myTablatures[ b ] = myTablatures[b + 1];
                  myTablatures[b + 1] = tab;
                 try {
                        currentTabEntry ++;
                        shwEntry(currentTabEntry);
                     }
                     
                 catch (Exception ex) {
                     System.out.println("Error");
                 }
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`.  This allows you define the sort order by comparing objects based on your needs.

For example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        List<Integer> ranks = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}));
        Collections.shuffle(ranks);

        Guitar[] guitars = new Guitar[10];
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            guitars[index] = new Guitar("Tab " + Integer.toString(index), ranks.remove(0));
        }

        System.out.println("Unsorted = " + Arrays.toString(guitars));

        Arrays.sort(guitars, new Comparator<Guitar>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Guitar o1, Guitar o2) {
                return o1.getRank() - o2.getRank();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Sorted = " + Arrays.toString(guitars));
    }

    public class Guitar {

        public String tabName;
        public String eString;
        public String bString;
        public String gString;
        public String dString;
        public String aString;
        public String lowEString;
        public int rank;

        public Guitar(String tabName, int rank) {
            this.tabName = tabName;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        public int getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        public void setRank(int r) {
            rank = r;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[Guitar] " + tabName + " @ " + getRank();
        }
    }
}
```

Which can output something like...

```
Unsorted = [[Guitar] Tab 0 @ 10, [Guitar] Tab 1 @ 5, [Guitar] Tab 2 @ 2, [Guitar] Tab 3 @ 6, [Guitar] Tab 4 @ 4, [Guitar] Tab 5 @ 1, [Guitar] Tab 6 @ 3, [Guitar] Tab 7 @ 7, [Guitar] Tab 8 @ 9, [Guitar] Tab 9 @ 8]
  Sorted = [[Guitar] Tab 5 @ 1, [Guitar] Tab 2 @ 2, [Guitar] Tab 6 @ 3, [Guitar] Tab 4 @ 4, [Guitar] Tab 1 @ 5, [Guitar] Tab 3 @ 6, [Guitar] Tab 7 @ 7, [Guitar] Tab 9 @ 8, [Guitar] Tab 8 @ 9, [Guitar] Tab 0 @ 10]
```

See:

- [Comparator Interface in Java with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/)
- [Comparator and Comparable in](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable)
- [Arrays.sort() in Java with examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/)

for more details.

You may also want to have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

> Why wouldn't you just implement `Comparable` directly on the `Guitar` class?

Because that locks you into a single use case. What if you want to sort based on the name?  Or the tab scale?  Or some other set of properties?  Personally, I find creating custom `Comparator`s and overall better and cleaner solution, but that's me

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!! Ill look that up.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... how can I put these guitars tab entries into a algorithm (from lowest to highest rank). ..."*

By *"rank"*, I presume you mean the order in which the note, or chord, is played.

Utilize *[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) structures* to define each element, of a piece of *[tablature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablature)*.
Here is an example.

Use an *[enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)* to define the strings.
Note, I'm using *"String"* as a title, so *"java.lang.String"* is needed to define any actual *String* properly.

```java
enum String {
    e, B, G, D, A, E
}
```

Use a *class* to define a *"glyph"*, which will be the fret number, and any appended symbol, e.g., *[hammer-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablature#Guitar_tablature)*, *bend*, etc.
We'll use an actual *String* *object* here; although we could, even further, define this element.
For now, this will suffice.

```java
class Glyph {
    java.lang.String g;
}
```

Similarly, use another *class* to define a *"note"*, effectively a *String* and a *Glyph*.

```java
class Note {
    String s;
    Glyph g;
}
```

Again, another *class* to define a *"step"*; the vertical set of *notes*, plausibly a *chord*.
I imagine you can add a *duration* field here, as well.

```java
class Step {
    List<Note> s;
}
```

And finally, a *class* to define the entire *musical piece*; a *tablature*.

```java
class Tablature {
    List<Step> t;
}
```

For proper usage, we'll need to expand these *classes*, providing *[constructor methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)*, *[accessors methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*, and any other relevant functionality.

Here is a re-factor.

```java
enum String {
    e, B, G, D, A, E
}
```

```java
class Glyph {
    java.lang.String g;

    Glyph(java.lang.String g) {
        this.g = g;
    }
}
```

```java
class Note {
    String s;
    Glyph g;

    Note(String s, Glyph g) {
        this.s = s;
        this.g = g;
    }
}
```

```java
class Step {
    List<Note> s = new ArrayList<>();

    void addNote(String s, java.lang.String g) {
        this.s.add(new Note(s, new Glyph(g)));
    }

    void addChord(Note... n) {
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList(n));
    }
}
```

```java
class Tablature {
    List<Step> t = new ArrayList<>();

    void append(Step... s) {
        t.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        boolean c;
        for (String s : values()) {
            b.append("%s|---".formatted(s));
            for (Step st : t) {
                c = false;
                for (Note n : st.s)
                    if (n.s == s) {
                        b.append("%s---".formatted(n.g.g));
                        c = true;
                    }
                if (!c) b.append("----");
            }
            b.append("%n".formatted());
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

From here, we can create a *"chord"*, and add it to a *Tablature* instance.

```java
Tablature t = new Tablature();
Step chordE = new Step();
chordE.addNote(e, "0");
chordE.addNote(B, "0");
chordE.addNote(G, "1");
chordE.addNote(D, "2");
chordE.addNote(A, "2");
chordE.addNote(E, "0");
t.append(chordE);
```

Output

```
e|---0---
B|---0---
G|---1---
D|---2---
A|---2---
E|---0---
```

Here is some, *"[Smoke on the Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_on_the_Water)"*.

```java
Tablature t = new Tablature();
Step s1, s2, s3;
s1 = new Step();
s1.addNote(D, "5");
s1.addNote(A, "5");
s2 = new Step();
s2.addNote(G, "3");
s2.addNote(D, "3");
s3 = new Step();
s3.addNote(G, "5");
s3.addNote(D, "5");
t.append(s1, s2, s3);
```

```
e|---------------
B|---------------
G|-------3---5---
D|---5---3---5---
A|---5-----------
E|---------------
```

Comment: *"Based on the rank that I set them to in that part of the forms textField?"* - Although I enjoyed the music theory ;)

Comment: Thanks,  thats A very Great Concept, Thanks For Replying.

Comment: @smouvfox805, encapsulating the data this way, will allow for scalability, and simpler re-factoring.  For example, incorporate a _rank_ field to _Step_, and sort the values with a _Comparator_, demonstrated by _MadProgrammer_.